# How can I increase/decrease FancyBox2 popup size after popup display and appending data which is return by an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

I have an application in which I am displaying a fancybox. After displaying a fancybox I am making an ajax call and that call return some data.

When I append that data into fancybox I am getting scrollbars. I want to resize fancybox whenever any data added/removed in fancybox dynamically. How can I do that?

Comment: if using fancybox v2.x try calling the `$.fancybox.update()` method after appending the data into fancybox. For v1.3.4 call `$.fancybox.resize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks You All, finally i have found the solution, just add these replace this line in your fancybox origHeight = body.outerHeight(true); with origHeight = body.height()+10; and add this line too                                                     origWidth = body.width()+10;.

after that just set your height of fancybox to auto and call window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.update() after any append/ remove of your data. Like

```
$("a.fancy-view").click(function(){
  var viewID = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#"+viewID).fancybox({
      type: 'iframe',
      'autoSize': false,
      'autoDimensions'        :   false,
      href: $("#"+viewID).attr('href'),
      width:600,
      height:'auto',
      'beforeLoad': function(){
         $.fancybox.showLoading();
       }
    });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#append").click(function(){
$("#mydiv").html(anyhtmldata);
window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.update();
});
});
```

after done i have found that for what i am looking i got it.